# #!/usr/bin/python (sha-bang or she-bang)does not work in bash

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu

I have the following contents in the file

demo.py:- // executable bit set

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
```

i have used the command **bash demo.py** in the terminal and expecting that the
first line is interpreted by the bash and it handles the file to python interpreter.
But it calls the binary "/usr/bin/import"(figured using strace). The same is with **sh demo.py**.
However running **./demo.py** works. man bash says

"If  the program is a file beginning with #!, the remainder of the first
line specifies an interpreter for the program."

which is not happening.

Using bash version

$ bash --version

GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

in Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bash documentation is correct: when you enter `./demo.py` at the bash command prompt, bash uses the shebang line to figure out what executable will run the script.

When you do `bash demo.py` then of course bash is going to try to run it as a bash script. Because you told it to. (Imagine if you had a bash script with an incorrect shebang line -- how would you run it? By passing it directly to bash, in just this way.)

If you want to start another bash shell which runs your Python script, then use `bash -c ./demo.py` to execute `demo.py` *as a bash command* rather than as a bash script. But you shouldn't need to start another shell just to run a Python script.

Comment: No, bash doesn't look at the shebang line; it invokes the command via the kernal (by calling one of the `exec*()` functions), and the kernel interprets the `#!` line.

Comment: @KeithThompson are you sure, because any executable has to go through exec*() functions(CMIW). In that it should not matter how the script is called.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: Exactly. (I'm a bit confused, are you disagreeing with me?)

Answer (score 7):

I think you're confused with the meaning of the she-bang line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

This means that `./demo.py` will execute as `/usr/bin/python demo.py`.

However, with `/bin/bash demo.py`, `bash` will try to interpret `demo.py` as a shell script file and will fail, that is, `python` won't be executed.

Comment: is it anywhere documented that bash she-bang works only for interactive shell

Comment: @Talespin_Kit: No, because that's not the case.  The shebang is recognized by the kernel, not by bash.  Any time you execute your script *as a command*, the kernel will execute the specified shell and give it the name of the script as a command-line argument.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run it as `bash -c ./demo.py` or `sh -c ./demo.py`, otherwise each line from the file will be executed as a bash command (rather than executing the file using the she-bang).

Comment: No, just run it as `./demo.py`.  There's no reason to invoke a new shell just to invoke a single command.